# Spring Boot, Maven and missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Spring Boot (1.2.5.RELEASE) Web Application project (spring-boot-starter-web), built with Maven (3.3.3), runs when executing JAR file created in /target directory

```
java -jar magic-supplies-1.0.0.jar
```

But fails to execute when running maven command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

with the following stack trace:

```
16:32:36:125 | cogito.online.application.MagicSuppliesApplication.main() | Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:473)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at cogito.online.application.MagicSuppliesApplication.main(MagicSuppliesApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 13 more
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:473)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at cogito.online.application.MagicSuppliesApplication.main(MagicSuppliesApplication.java:10)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 13 more
```

It has a simple configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan ("cogito.online")
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-activemq.xml")
public class MagicSuppliesConfiguration {

}
```

and application class

```
@Import(MagicSuppliesConfiguration.class)
public class MagicSuppliesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MagicSuppliesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Again everything works, both web and jms requests, when running the executable JAR but fails when running the Maven Spring Boot command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...minus any snarky trolling on Maven ;)

Comment: Can u share the pom file ?

Comment: Remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from `MagicSuppliesConfiguration` and put a `@SpringBootApplication` on your `MagicSuppliesApplication`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that combination results in another error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null` when running `mvn spring-boot:run` but not running `java -jar magic-supplies-1.0.0.jar`. Same result as before.

Comment: Using Spring 4.2.1 and Boot 1.2.5 here are the dependencies `<!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: and plugin dependency - `            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>                               
            </plugin>`

Comment: Honestly, I think it may be a bug with the plugin. When I start the plugin using `mvn spring-boot:run` it reads and deletes a spring.xml from the ./target/classes directory. But when I run `java -jar magic-supplies-1.0.0.jar` it loads that file just fine (since it is packaged all together).